# Automating code signing with EV certificate

Tags: certificate, code-signing, electron-builder

Our company is planning to buy the EV certificate for code signing. 
We have automatic builds that should perform the signing, but from what we read, continuous integration tools will not work since the certificate comes with a hardware dongle. I've seen the workarounds, but most of them require either a windows machine or scripting to sign the apps. It feels a lot like a hack.

How do companies that have many products sign their apps, they can't be doing it by hand, can they?

What tools are there to automate the process? I mean there should be some software with an API where you can pass your files and it spits back a signed version of those files. Or something that could split the build process into multiple machines or containers.

How do you guys do it? We're building apps for Windows/macOS.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( We did not go with EV certificates.